# how to move a box from left to right and leave it there in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, animation

I want to move a box in it parent from left to right

and then leave it there till the user click on it and then move it back to left and leave it there till another click is done.

However I manage only to move from left to right. not leaving it to the right

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/switch_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_bg" 
        android:layout_gravity= "right"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/handle_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/handle" 

        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/switch_v_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/switch_v" />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/handle_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/handle" 

   android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/switch_v_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/switch_v" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

my transition xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="80%p" android:duration="600"/>
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
                android:toAlpha="0.1"/>
</set>
```

here is my class:

```
public class SettingsSwitchView extends RelativeLayout {

        private static final int TRANSITION_TIME = 1;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;


        private ImageView switch_bg;
        private RelativeLayout boxImage_left;
        private ImageView vImage_left;
        private RelativeLayout boxImage_right;
        private ImageView vImage_right;

        private boolean isChecked;

        public SettingsSwitchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_switch, this);

            switch_bg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.switch_bg);
            boxImage_left = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.handle_left);
            vImage_left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.switch_v_left);

            boxImage_right = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.handle_right);
            vImage_right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.switch_v_right);

            isChecked =  false; //benda: read from config file

            switch_bg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    //              com.waze.view.anim.AnimationUtils.openNavigateScreenWithFadeIn(vImage);

                    //              
    //              image1.setAlpha(progress);
    //              Image2.setAlpha(100-progress);

                    if (!isChecked)
                    {

                    Animation animation = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AppService.getAppContext(), com.waze.R.anim.slide_from_left_with_fade_out);
                    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    boxImage_left.startAnimation(animation);

                    boxImage_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    boxImage_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Animation animation = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AppService.getAppContext(), com.waze.R.anim.slide_from_right_with_fade_in);
                        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                        boxImage_right.startAnimation(animation);

                        boxImage_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        boxImage_right.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    }

            TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) switch_bg.getBackground();
            transition.reverseTransition(TRANSITION_TIME);

            isChecked = !isChecked;

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
         TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,50,0,0);
            anim.setDuration(1000);          
            v.startAnimation(anim);
```

this move to right.for left change parametes.